# How to get selected value from DevExpress comboBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I'm trying to get the text from the selected value in the combo box by using:

```
lblMessage.Text = cmbArchivoModificado.SelectedItem.Text;
```

I've already set the valuefield and textfield on the combobox settings, but visual studio keep telling me this:

> nullreferenceException was unhandled by user code.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "ASP.NET - c# - " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Please show the code where the problem is occurring, and post the full exception output. Also, you may want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net

Comment: Please share the markup and code

Answer (score 2):

Usually the problem, when the ASPxComboBox's SelectedItem / SelectedIndex is incorrect, occurs when the [ASPxComboBox.ValueType](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxComboBox_ValueTypetopic) property is specified incorrectly.

Ensure that the ValueType is set, corresponding to the "[Data Type Mappings (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx)" table.

Try to use the ASPxComboBox.Value property instead:

```
lblMessage.Text = cmbArchivoModificado.Value != null
     ?  cmbArchivoModificado.Value.ToString()
     :  string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you need to first check whether cmbArchivoModificado.SelectedItem is null.

```
lblMessage.Text = cmbArchivoModificado.SelectedItem == null ? "NA" 
    : cmbArchivoModificado.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the value on this way:

```
var value = comboboxExample.SelectecText;
```

or

```
var value = comboboxExample.EditValue;
```